# Three.js Positionning objects according their coordinates

Tags: javascript, three.js

In a Json file I get the descriptions of a SVG set of lines drawn on a map:

```
   <line x1="30" y1="232" x2="44" y2="232" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"></line>
   <line x1="44" y1="232" x2="48" y2="210" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"></line>
   ...
```

I know the original Leaflet map size: 948 x 412px. Once the SVG is created by User, I generate a image of the map which is used as background plane (called 'base') in a webGL 3D reconstruction of the scene. The question is: how to position the SVG lines at their right places?

The first step was to translate the x1,x2,y1,y2 values of each line according the 'base' size in Three. The next one is to find how to place each line...

```
    sizemap[0]/2 and sizemap[1]/2 are the exact 'base' center values (left and top)
    x1, x2, y1, y2 are the recalculated original SVG values

    // position of each line from 'base' center

    from_pos_left = x1 - sizemap[0]/2; 
    from_pos_top = y1 - sizemap[1]/2;
    to_pos_left = x2 - sizemap[0]/2; 
    to_pos_top = y2 - sizemap[1]/2;

    // calculate the angle and length of each line

    deltaX = to_pos_left - from_pos_left;
    deltaY = to_pos_top - from_pos_top;
    angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
    deltaX *= deltaX;
    deltaY *= deltaY;
    length = Math.floor(Math.sqrt( deltaX + deltaY));

    // then position center of the line on 'base' (color and thickness are in mesh material)

    center_left =  ( (to_pos_left - from_pos_left) /2 ) - sizemap[0]/2 + x1 ;
    center_top =  ( (to_pos_top - from_pos_top) /2 ) - sizemap[1]/2 + y1;

    line = new THREE.Mesh( lineGeometry, lineMaterial );
    line.position.set( center_left, 3, center_top ); 
    line.rotation.y = angle;                            
    scene.add(line);
```

... but it doen't work as expected.
To test it easier I've created fictive lines with round values:

```
    x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 200; y2 = 200;  
    x1 = 400; y1 = 200; x2 = 200; y2 = 400;
```

works well. But:

```
    x1 = 200; y1 = 200; x2 = 400; y2 = 200;
```

doesn't. Length and position are always OK but not the angle. I've tried to apply a correction to angle depending x1/x2 and y1/y2 positions:

```
    f = Math.abs(x1/x2) + Math.abs(y1/y2)
    angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) + Math.PI*f;
```

OK, now `x1 = 200; y1 = 200; x2 = 400; y2 = 200;` works well... but `x1 = 200; y1 = 150; x2 = 400; y2 = 250;` doesnt.

I'm sure I'm close to solution but can't find it. Someone here knows the right formula?

-------------- EDIT

Just try another trigo formula:

```
long = Math.hypot(x2-x1,y2-y1);
angle = Math.asin( (y2-y1) /long);
```

Length and center pos are always OK but not the angle... Angle error is not the same as above but still wrong.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: OK I'll prepare a ligthest version. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Also if you can add more details about the SVG data input, since SVG uses coordinates space it's unclear what is the SVG's width/height in units. <svg width="948" height="412"></svg>?

Comment: fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Wolden/og425f3b/

Try to change x1,x2,y1,y2 values. Green and yellow verticals define starting and ending position on expected line (red). Changing values always keep the center of the red line on the expected position (right between the 2 green and yellow controls) and length, but angle fails.

Comment: when searching to add a value to angle to obtain the correct one for 0,0,600,400 I've found  
line.rotation.y = angle + Math.PI/8;

for 0,0,500,400 : line.rotation.y = angle + Math.PI/14;

Comment: 100,100,500,40 : line.rotation.y = angle + Math.PI/11;

400,0,0,400 :  line.rotation.y = angle + Math.PI/2;

Answer (score 0):

ooooooooh no, the correct answer was so easy to find :-)

```
  angle = Math.asin( (x2-x1) /length); // instead of (y2-y1)
```

see fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Wolden/og425f3b/